# Can not use credentialType='apn' credentials for FCM notifications

Tags: android, twilio, voice

I have registered with Twilio voice on an iOS device for an specific **Identity** to receive VoIP calls.

Now when I register on an **Android device** with the **same Identity** with the correct Push Notification SID, although I receive incoming calls but I get the following error for every single call on the Twilio console too.

```
Type of credential provided in access token does not match that of the registration. For example you included the SID of a APS type Credential in the access token for an Android application using GCM.
```

And in the message text I have the following:

```
Can not use credentialType='apn' credentials for FCM notifications
```

I have double checked and my **Push Notification SID** is correct and included in my access token on client side.

Is Twilio trying to call previously registered devices?

This is a very weird issue.

Comment: I just figured out if I change the Identity of my client to a new, this issue won't happen. This is a previously generated token issue that for some reason Twilio tries to send notifications to old devices. Now my question is how I can delete old tokens for an identity on the server side?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? I am getting same issue.. I am trying to register one identity to android and other identity in iOS.  I am using PHP server. My Question is what will be in PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID? As I am using FCM in Android and APN in iOS and both have different SID's. Same time I am able to call with Android to Android and iOS to iOS but Android to iOS call is not working

Comment: how I can delete old tokens for an identity on the server side?
@Alex you can unregister Twilio SDK has this functionality